# Adding dynamic ExpandableListView inside main.xml

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Is there a site where I can find the inner workings of the BaseExpandableListAdapter? I read the API and I still don't understand how it loops through the whole array that is supplied to provide the view. I'm having problems with my own implementation. I can't create a whole list of expandable lists without using ExpandableListActivity, even though both are the same. It's supposed to retrieve strings from the database and create an expandablelistview out of each one, and add all the created expandablelists to a linearlayout inside main.xml. What happens is that only the expandablelistview for the first string is shown. Here's the snippet

Main Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
DBAdapter groupTable = new DBAdapter(this);
ExpandableListView groupLabel;
GroupAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

       groupTable.open();
    adapter = new GroupAdapter(groupTable.getAllGroups());
    retrieveExpandables(adapter);
       groupTable.close();
    Button addGroupButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addGroup);
    addGroupButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void retrieveExpandables(GroupAdapter adapter) { 
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.grouplist);
    LinearLayout groupLayout =    
             (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grouplistview, null);

    ExpandableListView groupExpandableList = 
             (ExpandableListView)groupLayout.findViewById(R.id.groupLabel);
    groupExpandableList.setAdapter(adapter);

    layout.addView(groupLayout);
}
```

BaseExpandableListAdapter class:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView instanceof ViewGroup)
        return (ViewGroup) convertView;
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.grouplisttext, null);
    TextView groupLabel = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.groupLabel);
    groupLabel.setText(groups[groupPosition].name);
    groupLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.d("A1", "This part repeating");
    return item;
}
```

XML file for the TextView that will be the expandable list title

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/groups"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/groupLabel"
              android:textSize="24sp"
              android:text="asdf"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="40dip"
              android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
              android:gravity="center_vertical" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

XML file for the ExpandableListView

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/groups"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/groupLabel"
              android:textSize="24sp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="40dip" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Sorry if I posted too much code, I tried removing as much unnecessary information as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where the problem went wrong. Apparently I got the LinearLayout and the ScrollView inside the main.xml interchanged, and the method for getViewGroup class was wrong. It's all good now